# What did Shouko say to Ishida in the coming of age ceremony that made Ueno jealous?

Tags: koe-no-katachi, sign-language

I don't understand what they are saying. Could someone translate this?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Four fingers raised, thumb pulled in is "ke", while full fist means "sa".
[image][image]

Together they are "kesa", which means "this morning".

Shouko is referring to the hardships they had that morning with putting on their kimono, doing their hair, etc. We know Ishida knows about it because Shouko's mother has shown him a picture about the girls getting ready,
[image]

so he reacts with "beautiful".

Explanation for the sign he makes :
[image]

Comment: could you tell me where did you find the "Let's learn japanse sign language" image ?

Comment: but why Ueno said "Stop Flirting", i didnt quite get it at that part.
I like where you put the sign language image in your answer, first time i see that kind of image ( i  never search information about sign language before )

Comment: @Gagantous: I found the "Let's learn japanse sign language" image [here](http://aminoapps.com/page/anime/5623792/basic-japanese-sign-language). They're made by anonblack, a founding member of [Futari Wa Pretty Anon](http://prettyanonymo.us/) scanlation group. Sadly, they only did the firs 30 chapters or so, they dropped it after the series was licensed in the US.

Comment: About Ueno: I might be wrong, but if I'm not mistaken Ueno doesn't know sign language. So she doesn't know what the two are saying to each other, only sees them signing, and even if she does understand it she missed at least the first sign (she isn't looking at Shouko), so she likely simply misunderstood the situation.